# Using Selenium IDE, how to test CSS style information

Tags: selenium

I am testing a plugin which makes changes to the CSS of HTML elements – how can I use Selenium commands to verify/test these CSS changes?

Answer (score 5):

You can use CSS classes and then check if the element has a specific class.
In Selenium IDE :

```
Command: assertAttribute
Target: document.getElementById('header')[0]@class
Value: myHeader
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Selenium IDE is mis-sold as a Record and Replay tool. Selenium IDE is actually a record, **tweak** and replay tool.

The **tweak** part is because the IDE can't record everything that you want. I recommend that you create your test from scratch by hand to get it to check the elements CSS.